# Is the language of palindromes context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Is the language $\{ w=w^R \mid w \in \{0,1\}^* \}$ a context-free language?

I am confused in deciding whether the language is context-free or not, that is one of my problems, I do a pumping lemma proof and what I get is that it is not a context-free language, but I want to make sure again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of palindromes is one of the standard examples of a non-regular context-free language. It is generated by the context-free grammar
$$
S \to 0S0 \mid 1S1 \mid 0 \mid 1 \mid \epsilon
$$

Comment: Should the CFG in chomsky normal form to explain whether the language is context free?

Comment: No. It is well-known that any language described by a context-free grammar is context-free. Indeed, many people *define* context-free languages this way.